# understanding reflexive transitive closure

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

Suppose I have the following relation
$$R = \{(1,1), (2,3), (3,1)\}$$
To make it reflexive we add the following missing pairs:
$$ \{(2,2), (3,3)\}$$
Now I wonder how to find the reflexive transitive closure of that relation?

Comment: add ${(1,2),(2,1)}$

Comment: Do you mean that $$R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3), (2,3), (3,1),(1,2),(2,1) \}$$ ?

Comment: Yes. I believe that is reflexive transitive, yes? I don't remember the definition of transitive though.

Comment: I'm supposing that *transitive* must implies that from (1,2) and (2,3), (1,3) follows ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflexive and transitive are two different things.
Transitive means: if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$ then $a \sim c$. While reflexive means that $a\sim a$ in your realtion.

You have $R = \{(1,1), (2,3), (3,1)\}$ and you want it to be closed under transitivity . Since $2\sim 3$ and $3\sim 1$ you must have $2\sim 1$ so you add $(2,1)$.

---

**Edit:**

Suppose that $R$ is a relation on a set $A$. The reflexive transitive closure of $R$ is the smallest relation $S$ on $A$ such that:

$R⊆S$;
$S$ is reflexive;
and $S$ is transitive.

Comment: "Reflexive and transitive are two different things" - that's true. But there exist also something called 'reflexive transitive closure' and that's what I am looking for

Comment: I edited my answer. you can see that adding $(2,1)$ does the job.

Comment: I got it now :) thanks